# Element is removed after transitionLeaveTimeout - but how come not inserted after transitionEnterTimeout

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue, with the **Animation One or Zero Items** of the Animation page - http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html#animating-one-or-zero-items

My component shows a message initially. Then when it gets the next message, it fades out the "leaving" element in 1second. Because I set `transitionLeaveTimeout` to 1second as well, this element is removed after the fade out completes.

However, I set `transitionEnterTimeout` to be 1second (and then i tried 2second), however, the "entering" element is inserted as first child immediately on start of the "leaving". How come the "entering" element is not inserted AFTER the `transitionEnterTimeout`? Is there any way to make this happen?

The reason I ask is because if both are present, then the "leaving" element gets shifted down by line-height. I can't do CSS tricks like -100% line height and others as the CSS is a bit complex.

Here is a copy paste eample that shows this issue:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.14.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fb.me/react-dom-0.14.4.js"></script>
        <script>

            var MyStore = {};

            function init() {               
                var TheThing = React.createClass({
                    displayName: 'TheThing',
                    getInitialState: function() {
                        return {
                            msg: this.props.msg
                        };
                    },
                    componentDidMount: function() {
                            MyStore.setState = this.setState.bind(this);
                    },
                    render: function() {
                        return React.createElement(React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup, {transitionName:'thing', transitionEnterTimeout:6000, transitionLeaveTimeout:3000},
                            React.createElement('div', {key:this.state.msg},
                                this.state.msg
                            )
                        );
                    }
                });

                ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(TheThing, {msg:'initial'}), document.getElementById('message'));

                setTimeout(function() {
                    MyStore.setState({msg:'hi'})
                }, 6000)

                setTimeout(function() {
                    MyStore.setState({msg:'bye'})
                }, 12000)
            }
            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
        </script>
        <style>
            .thing-enter,
            .thing-appear {
              opacity: 0;
            }

            .thing-enter.thing-enter-active,
            .thing-appear.thing-appear-active {
              opacity: 1;
              transition: opacity 6s ease 3s;
            }

            .thing-leave {
              opacity: 1;
            }

            .thing-leave.thing-leave-active {
              opacity: 0;
              transition: opacity 3s ease;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="message"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As far as I can tell you have not set any classes that reflect the `transitionName` you have set in `ReactCSSTransitionGroup`. You can easily, using CSS add a class, that will delay the `enter` of a new component by the number of seconds it takes for the `leave` to go away.

Since you have set `transitionName="fade-out-then-in"` you can do something along the lines of: 

`.fade-out-then-in-enter { transition-delay: 1s; -webkit-transition-delay: 1s; }`

The timeout values are set so that you can ensure that the transitions/animations will be cut/done if they surpass the given value.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I removed that example, it was just a shorter version so I had it there, please see the full exmaple using `thing`, it has the classes. It is copy paste, you can see here that the enter happens as soon as the leaving animation starts. Why isn't the element being inserted after the delay of `transitionEnterTimeout`?

Comment: it is my experience that timeout values do not equal delay for inserting a transition, but rather a timeout interval within which each transition need to happen. Try to look at the elements in dev tools or similar to see what's going on when a transition is triggered. In your css, you're transitioning both enter and leave, and my suggestion would be to add a transition-delay to enter, which match seconds for leave transition. Make sure that both timeout values at least are same as the enter and leave transition values plus delay, i.e. For enter: 6 sec. + delay of 3 sec. = 9000.

Comment: Darn, thanks though thomas  :)